# Python converting json to pandas df shows all fields a Type 'Object'

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm reading in a json string using pandas into a data frame.  When I view the dataframe info, every column shows as a data type of 'Object', instead of the actual data type.  I was hoping to iterate the columns and if a certain data type then perform an action on each row.

Any ideas why it shows each data type as Object and is there anything I can do to get it to assess the true data type of each column?

Thanks

My python code is

```
import pandas as pd
fInput = '\x\y\file.txt'
with open(finout, ecoding='utf-16') as inputfile:
    df = pd.read_json(inputfile)
df.info()
```

My json structure is:

```
[
{
"id" : "123",
"created" : "2020-12-31T12:10:32Z",
"state" : "Open"
},
{
"id" : "456",
"created" : "2020-12-31T12:10:32Z",
"state" : "Close"
}
]
```

Comment: This is not a valid json structure.

Comment: apols, corrected some typos.

Comment: Pandas try to infer the datatype when you use `read_json` (for numbers). In your example, id dtype is int64.

Answer (score 0):

If pandas fails at infering series dtype, you can set it yourself:

```
df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

You can also be specific to which type you want to set a given series.

```
df['created'] = df['created'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

also works with other data types, for example:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype('int32')
```